# how detect boundary of fingerprint image

Tags: matlab

I am working on **fingerprint image**. I extract the minutiae point of image. there are a lot of minutiae in boundary but they are false . I want to remove them but I don't know how detect boundary of fingerprint.

Here is my image after detect minutiae :

[image]
[it is my original picture(gray)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLkND.png)

Can anybody help me to write matlab code for it?

Comment: can you attach the image without the minutiae and add supply you code for adding them?